# Mongoid paper clip photo is removed when parent.update_attributes!(attr) called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip

I have 2 models

The `User` model embeds many `pictures` as follows

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :user_name, type: String
  embeds_many :pictures, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end
```

The `Picture` model is implemented as follows

```
class Picture
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :description,   type: String

  has_mongoid_attached_file :photo,
  default_url: '',
  default_style: :thumb,
  url: "/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  styles: {
    original: ['2000x1200>',  :jpg],
    thumb:    ['600x400#',    :jpg]
  },
  convert_options: {
    all: '-quality 90 -strip -background black -flatten +matte'
  }
  ...
end
```

---

The problem is in the `user_controller#update`

```
def update
   ...
   @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
   ...
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, pictures:[:id, :description])
end
```

I expected this `#update` to update the description of the picture with the `id` passed... and it does.
***but the uploaded picture is removed after this update ?***

how do i update the `description` of the uploaded photo without it getting removed after using `@user.update_attributes!(user_params)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested!

```
pictures_params = params[:user].delete(:pictures)
@user.pictures.where(:id.in => pictures_params.map(&:id)).each do |pic|
  pic.set(:description, pictures_params.find{|p| p[:id] == pic.id}[:description])
end
```

Comment: i did it in a similar way... but isn't there a better way... or configuration... this code looks smelly and will be hard to maintain in the future... and why did `update_attributes` over-ridded the embedded docs photo... when it has no photo ?

Comment: Embedded collection is array of hashes so when you say `update_attributes(:pictures => ...)` that's meaning you changed the value of this field means you changed the embedded collection

Comment: so there is no other approach in updating embedded documents ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve the problem but i think there is a better approach for solving this issue

```
  # get the user hash to update both pictures and user
  user_params_hash = user_params

  # remove the picture from the hash to separate the updating of pictures from users
  picture_params_hash = user_params_hash.delete 'pictures'

  # update each picture description to avoid removing the photo
  unless picture_params_hash.nil?
    picture_params_hash.each do |picture_hash|

      picture = @user.pictures.find_or_create_by(id: picture_hash[:id])
      picture.description = picture_hash[:description]
      picture.save!
    end
  end

  # update the user attributes only without touching the embedded pictures
  @user.update_attributes!(user_params_hash)
end
```